# Restart IIS6 application pool - ADSI error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Not sure what the eff' is wrong! I am using Powershell 2.0 on Windows 7. Had this same script working on Windows XP , am i just missing something?

```
$server = "server1-vm1.prod.ds.russell.com"
$name = "Superduper_Reports"
$iis = [ADSI]"IIS://$server/W3SVC/AppPools/$name"
$iis.psbase.invoke("recycle")
```

Error (that invoke looks okay to me?):

```
Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
At line:3 char:19
+ $iis.psbase.invoke <<<< ("recycle")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

When just running `$iis` variable i get this error:

```
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "PSComputerName": "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

Roooarr! I'd rather use ADSI over WMI! Any help? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use `WebAdministration` module for that

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-Command -Module WebAdministration
Get-ChildItem IIS:
```

You will find a lots of Cmdlets to admin IIS and a new drive IIS:

You will find on [this Microsoft Web site](http://technet.microsoft.com/us-us/library/ee909471%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) some explanations.

Comment: Thanks!  Would you mind fixing the typo in your snippet?  add the d to Get-ChildItem IIS:

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590094/recycling-iis-application-pool-using-powershell-exception-calling-recycle) has a WMI script which has been stated to work.

Alternatively ADSI equivalent would look something like this ...

http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2010/12/16/powershell-ndash-recycle-all-iis-app-pools.aspx

```
function Recycle-AppPools {

    param(
    [string] $server = "3bhs001",
    [int] $mode = 1, # ManagedPipelineModes: 0 = integrated, 1 = classic
    ) 

    $iis = [adsi]"IIS://$server/W3SVC/AppPools"
    $iis.psbase.children | %{ 
        $pool = [adsi]($_.psbase.path); 
        if ($pool.AppPoolState -eq 2 -and $pool.ManagedPipelineMode -eq $mode) {
           # AppPoolStates:  1 = starting, 2 = started, 3 = stopping, 4 = stopped          
           $pool.psbase.invoke("recycle") 
        }
   }

}
```

You can't recycle a stopped AppPool however so you need to check for that.